# Forecasting elections by using survey data (in R)

Tags: r, panel-data, forecasting, plm, dlm

> In advance: my sincere apologies for any incompleteness, lack of
>   knowledge and general stupidity in this post. I am doing my ultimate
>   best to be as complete and thorough as possible - but I could imagine
>   that this question should be posted in a more statistical forum.

**Context**

As the titles states; I am currently trying to forecast the Dutch municipal election results based on an annual survey. The survey is send out to a random sample of 10.000 inhabitants of the municipality, of which 35% is the average response rate.

The survey data is available for 16 years (and can be grouped on a neighborhood level) and elections are held every 4 years. The outcomes of each election are known and grouped by neighborhood (as well).

**Approach**

The Dutch election system is an open party list system of proportional representation. In previous research forecasters have used 'Dynamic Linear Models' (also available as an R-package) for this purpose (use in elections: http://umu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:871401/FULLTEXT01.pdf).

I am aware of the fact this is 'pooled cross sectional data' and have discovered that there is a package available that deals with DLM for Panel Data. Is anyone aware of the existence of a DLM package that deals with Pooled cross sectional data or could, with the data described above, plm do the job?

Would you suggest a different approach to coping with this problem?

Please; if anything is unclear - ask.

Comment: This isn't worded as a specific programming question and therefore is not appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you need help choosing an appropriate statistical model for your data, you should be asking over at [stats.se] where statistical questions are on-topic.

Comment: Much appreciated! I thought my question was more on the topic of appropriate package, rather than model, as an excuse for the misplacement - but one is a result of the other, I presume.

Answer (score 1):

What type of data are you dealing with? Is it continuous or categorical data? Or a mix of both? How many features are present in the dataset?

I'm not familiar with DLM's, but I do work with forecasting models. One of the most simplistic forecasting models you can develop is a Naive Bayes model, and it can often outperform some of the more complicated algorithms. It's really easy to implement in R too. But it depends on the data you're using.

If you let me know the type of data/features you're working with, I may be able to suggest some ways for you to proceed.

Comment: This isn't really an "answer." It's more like a number of questions couched as an answer. As such, it is really a comment and should be treated as such.

Comment: Eoin, thanks for your response. 

I've worked with Naive Bayes and Bayesian models have been used for election forecasting purposes with proper results. It is both continuous (age, income etc.), as well as categorical (gender, Likert scale questions). The number of features is between 50-60, varying from year to year (not every question returns on an annual basis).

Comment: I know the package I work with for Bayesian models only deals with discrete data, but there's definitely others out there for doing both. You could try Logistic Regression as another possibility. Not only will it deal with both continuous and discrete data, but it will also allow you to evaluate the significance of your features. There are tons of examples on here showing how to implement such a model in R. If you want some suggestions, just let me know.